# Query multiple date ranges, return only specific key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo, I have a documents that look like the following:

```
dateRange: [{
    "price": "200",
    "dateStart": "2014-01-01",
    "dateEnd": "2014-01-30"
},

{
    "price": "220",
    "dateStart": "2014-02-01",
    "dateEnd": "2014-02-15"
}]
```

Nice and simple right? Just dates and prices. Now, the tricky party I'm is how would I go about creating a query to find the dateRange that fits with 2014-01-12, and then JUST return the **price** after it's found instead of the entire array of dateRanges?

These dateRanges can get quite large, and I'm trying to minimize the amount of data returned (if this is possible at all with Mongo). Note, the date format I can change up if required, I was just using the above for example purposes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator, which is only valid in versions 2.2 upward. You will also need to make sure you use [multikey indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/).

edit: To be clear you will also have to use the [$elemMatch *find* operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as pointed out in comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002221/mongo-query-multiple-date-ranges-return-only-specific-key#comment31564887_21002604).

This being said, I agree with the gist of comment by [mnemosyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002401/294311). It would be better to have each element of the array represented as a single document.

quick example of $elemMatch to demonstrate the projection. Simply add $elemMatch to the find as well.

```
> db.test.save ( {
  _id: 1,
  zipcode: 63109,
  students: [
               { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
               { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
               { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
            ]
 } );

> db.test.find( { zipcode: 63109 }, { students: { $elemMatch: { school: 102 } } } ).pretty() );
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "students" : [
        {
            "name" : "john",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I agree that you'll have to use `$elemMatch` to find correct matches in the first place (otherwise the `$lt`/`$gt` criteria will be matched on *any* of the array indices), but that won't save you from getting the entire document returned, which was the OP's question.

Comment: $elemMatch does a projection.

Comment: I see, there are two different `$elemMatch`: a query operator and a projection operator, the latter being quite a bit newer. For the OP's scenario, he'd *also* have to use an `$elemMatch` query operator though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem with that schema is that it uses large embedded arrays - this can be quite inefficient, because a mongodb query will always find a document, not a subset of an embedded object. Even if you're using a projection, mongodb will have to read the entire object internally, so if the array becomes huge, say 100k entries, that will slow things down to a halt.

Why not simply separate these array elements into documents, e.g.

```
{ 
  price : 200,
  productId : ObjectId("foo"), // or whatever the price refers to
  dateStart : "2014-01-01",
  dateEnd : "2013-01-30"
}
```

This way, mongodb doesn't need to pull the entire object with all prices, but only the prices that match your date range. This will minimize the amount of data transferred. You can then also use the [query projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) to only return the `price`, i.e. `db.collection.find({ criteria }, {"price" : 1, "_id" : 0})`.

Of course, the number of objects will increase dramatically, but efficient indexing will solve that problem. The only inefficiency induced is the duplication of the `productId`, which is cheaper than dealing with huge embedded arrays.

P.S: I'd suggest using actual dates (`ISODate`) instead of strings, even if their format is sortable.